# Specifying GUID causes camera1394 to fail. [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: Could not find camera with guid

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 cameras connected via firewire, and can open either one independently, when I dont specify the guid. However, when the guid is specified with the command:

```
rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node _guid:=b09d01008fe780
```

it gives the following output:

```
[ INFO] [1321932109.948708636]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1321932109.949074860]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/igvc/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ERROR] [1321932109.949321389]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/igvc/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1321932109.949433333]: Camera calibration file /home/igvc/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1321932110.109780362]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe780
[ INFO] [1321932110.112069001]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe77e
[ WARN] [1321932110.112333326]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: Could not find camera with guid b09d01008fe780
[ INFO] [1321932110.116237817]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe780
[ INFO] [1321932110.118381988]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe77e
[ WARN] [1321932110.118514197]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: Could not find camera with guid b09d01008fe780
[ INFO] [1321932110.122364814]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe780
[ INFO] [1321932110.124582016]: Found camera with GUID b09d01008fe77e
[ERROR] [1321932110.124722269]: [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: Could not find camera with guid b09d01008fe780
```

I need the images from both cameras for stereo vision.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12013/specifying-guid-causes-camera1394-to-fail.-%5Bcamera%5D-device-open-failed:-%5Bcamera1394::open%5D:-could-not-find-camera-with-guid/) by [wpi_igvc12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1424/wpi_igvc12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wpi_igvc12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1424/wpi_igvc12/) on 2011-12-20**:
yes, I get the same error when I specify b09d01008fe77e

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-21**:
Strange. Do you get the same error opening b09d01008fe77e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While looking at this problem again, I counted the number of GUID bytes. There should be eight, but there are only seven.

Perhaps your camera GUIDs have a leading zero byte. Try opening them like this:

```
rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node _guid:=00b09d01008fe780
```

I think that will work. If so, we should fix the driver to print GUIDs with the appropriate number of leading zeros.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-18**:
Your are welcome, sorry for the problem. I have opened a defect ticket to get this fixed in the next release: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5350

**Comment by [wpi_igvc12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1424/wpi_igvc12/) on 2012-01-18**:
The leading zeros issue was the cause. Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-11**:
It should just be modified to pad input GUIDs to the required eight bytes.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-11**:
Perhaps the driver should also be patched to output a warning if you specify a GUID with too few bytes?